# Redirect one URL to another using regex?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all requests to http://www.example.com/category/* to http://www.example.com.

This is what I tried:

```
RewriteRule http://www.example.com/category/.* http://www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Any ideas how to write the rule correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category/ /? [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: That looks promising, but if there are more parameters, they are not replaced, like in `http://www.example.com/category/magazine/?option=com_content&view=article&id=114&Itemid=66`. Any idea how to replace those, too?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below thing.

RewriteEngine  on

RewriteRule    "http://www.example.com/category/.*"  "http://www.example.com" [PT]